# How to display different strings on button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog

What I'm trying to do is to add multiple languages to my app, but I can't find a way of doing it. I've already created a folder called values-es with its strings.xml file translater into spanish. So, when I click Menu > Language > Spanish, I want the app to change to spanish. Is that possible? If it is, I would be much apreciated if you helped me :)

This is just a part of my java:

```
case id.language:

        CharSequence colors[] = new CharSequence[] {"English", "Spanish", "Portuguese", "Russian"};


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Language");

        builder.setItems(colors, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if(item == 0) {

                } else if(item == 1) {

                } else if(item == 2) {

                } else if(item == 3) {

                }
            }

        });
        builder.show();
        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    // Change locale settings in the app.
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase());
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```